# Calling unknown method: yii\web\Application::createUrl() in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii1.x

I have worked in `Yii1` and now I'm trying to use `Yii2`. I have installed composer and then installed basic app. But now i am getting this error when i try to access the basic app. Can anyone help me how to solve this issue?

**Error is:**

> Calling unknown method: yii\web\Application::createUrl()

Comment: It is not clear if you are getting this error with the basic application out of the box. Or did you add some code?

Comment: Also, explain how you installed the basic app.

Comment: @ShamonS find and fix `Yii::$app->createUrl()` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createUrl` it is a method of `UrlManager` class.

Usage: `Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['site/index']);`

Answer (score 2):

In Yii2 you can create url using `yii\helpers\Url`.

For example:

```
// Url::to() calls UrlManager::createUrl() to create a URL
$url = Url::to(['post/view', 'id' => 100]);
```

More info http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html